# Construction of the quadratic variation for Hilbert space valued local martingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $H$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a complete and right-continuous filtration of $\mathcal A$
- $X:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to H$ be an almost surely continuous local $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $X_0=0$ almost surely and $$X^n:=\langle X,e_n\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$

> How can we show that$^1$ $\left([X^n]_t\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is summable for all $t\ge0$ almost surely?

If $M$ is an $L^2$-bounded *strict* $\mathcal F$-martingale, then the claim can be proved easily:

- Let $$S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty[X^n]$$ and $t\ge0$
- Since $X$ is an $\mathcal F$-martingale, $$\operatorname E\left[\left(\left|X^n\right|^2-[X^n]\right)_t\right]=0\tag1$$ and hence $$\operatorname E[S_t]\xleftarrow{N\to\infty}\operatorname E\left[\sum_{n=1}^N[X^n]_t\right]=\operatorname E\left[\sum_{n=1}^N\left|\langle X_t,e_n\rangle_H\right|^2\right]\xrightarrow{N\to\infty}\operatorname E\left[\left\|X_t\right\|_H^2\right]\tag2$$
- By assumption, $X_t\in L^2(\operatorname P,H)$ and hence $$S_t<\infty\;\;\;\text{ almost surely}\tag3$$
- Since $[X^n]$ is nondecreasing for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $t$ was arbitrary, we obtain $$S_t<\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ almost surely}\tag4\;,$$ which is equivalent to the desired claim

> If $M$ is not $L^2$-bounded and only a local $\mathcal F$-martingale, then $(1)$ doesn't hold. Since this equation is the central argument of the proof above, I don't know how we're able to obtain the claim in the general case.
>
> However, the statement should be correct, since the desired summability result is crucial in the construction of the quadratic variation of $X$.

---

$^1$ If $M:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is an almost surely continuous local $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $M_0=0$ almost surely, then $[M]:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ denotes the quadratic variation of $M$, i.e. $[M]$ is the $\mathcal F$-adapted continuous stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ of locally bounded variation (and unique up to indistinguishability) such that $M^2-[M]$ is a local $\mathcal F$-martingale.